# Prepopuilate the current date time in yii2-datecontrol extension

Tags: php, date, gridview, yii2

I am working in a `yii2-grid - GridView` `kartik\datecontrol\DateControl`

I have used `DateControl` to select the current date-time.

Below is the code where I am trying to view default DateTime in the input.
But no value gets visible in the input box.

```
<?PHP 
    $form->field($model,'last_date')->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
        type'=>DateControl::FORMAT_DATETIME,
        pluginOptions' =>[
            defaultDate' => date('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a')
        ]                        
    ]);
?>
```

I have tried

```
date('d-m-Y h:i:s A')
```

also but it still displays the empty input box.

Also, try to give the model value to this attribute

```
$model->last_date = date('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a');
```

but this doesn't affect the input and input show empty.

so help me to get the default date-time display in the input box.

Answer (score 0):

The default date format is wrong. Should be,

```
date('d-m-Y h:m:s a');
```

I don't think you have to assign a current date yourself. Please follow the [documentation](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol)  or view demo [here](https://demos.krajee.com/datecontrol)

Comment: let me try this one first.

Answer (score 0):

By following this link
I got the answer to my issue of displaying the current date in the input.

[yii2-datecontrol/issues/17](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol/issues/17)

1. go to your configuration and check what formate you have set in `saveSettings`
2. use that formate without adding PHP in the date formate

Here is the final code which work

```
if(empty($model->expiry_date)){
    $model->expiry_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}   
echo $form->field($model,'expiry_date')->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
    'type'=>DateControl::FORMAT_DATETIME
]);
```

and here is the date set in the configuration. `web.php`

```
// format settings for saving each date attribute (PHP format example)
'saveSettings' => [
    Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'php:U', // saves as unix timestamp
    Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'php:H:i:s',
    Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
],
```